Put references in latex in order of their usage
I am stuck with a complex problem. My template of latex is arranging references alphabetically, but I want references in the order of first used. Please suggest me something so that this complex problem can be resolved. The template I am using is a springer template.

% \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\documentclass[runningheads, orivec]{llncs} 
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{physics}  % This package resolved the error due to \split
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}  % control figure float

%\usepackage{color}
%\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}
%\urlstyle{rm}
%
\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{Author1 \and
Author2}
% Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}} \and
%
\institute{University,USA\\\email{\{manynu\}@unv.com}}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:1}
\vspace{-1em}
The references are not comimg in order\cite{cite1}. Please help \cite{cite2, cite3, cite4}.



\section{Conclusion and Future Work}\label{sec:6}

\begin{credits}
\subsubsection{\ackname}
This research good.
\end{credits}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}


Maybe try \bibliographystyle{unsrt}?  (but if you plan to submit an article, use whatever the journal wants)

Thank you the response @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. Using \bibliographystyle{unsrt} works but it changes the way the author names are written. With \bibliographystyle{splncs04}, the authors names were like Chaudhary, M.  but if use \bibliographystyle{unsrt}, the authors names are like Manu Chaudhary. We want to do according to first usage and it is fine with conference instructions for final submission of paper.

Adding the below file to the project can resolve this issue:   https://rig.cs.luc.edu/~rig/home/tex/macros/svproc/styles/bibtex/splncs03_unsrt.bst
